# Make a point follow a rotating sprite

Tags: c#, xna, rotation

I have a rectangle with a square at its bottom. I also have code that makes the rectangle rotate around its origin which is at the top of this rectangle. Im trying to make the square at the bottom to always stay at the end of this rectangle even when its rotated. Hers a picture to illustrate my problem:

[image]

I see now that it wasn't such a good idea to make the square at the bottom white. So when i rotate the rectangle upwards to the right or upwards to the left, I want the square to keep staying at the end of this rectangle. Maybe there is a simple solution, but my knowledge isn't as good as it should be on this subject. Hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this aught to get you there.

```
float pendulumAngle;
Vector2 origin;
Vector2 squareTLcorner;//top left corner of square
Vector2 squareOffset;

void Reset()
{
  pendulumAngle = 0;
  origin = new Vector2(?.?f, ?.?f);// set to whatever you need
  squareTLcorner = new Vector2(?.?f, ?.?f); // set to whatever you need
  squareOffset = squareTLcorner - origin;

}

void UpdatePendulum(float angleMovedSinceLastFrame)
{
  pendulumAngle += angleMovedSinceLastFrame;
}

void UpdateSquarePosition()
{
  squareTLcorner = Vector2.Transform(squareOffset, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(pendulumAngle) + origin;

}

void DrawSquare()
{
  spriteBatch.Draw(sqTex,squareTLcorner, , ,pendulumAngle, ,  ,  ,  );// overload 6 of 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is passing a transformation matrix to the sprite batch.

```
 Rectangle Black = new Rectangle(0,0, 20, 100);
 Rectangle White = new Rectangle( Black.Left, Black.Bottom, Black.Width, Black.width);

 Vector2 Pivot= new Vector(100,100);
 vector2 Origin = new Vector2( 10,10);

 Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-Origin.X, -Origin.Y) 
                  * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle) 
                  * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Pivot);

 SpriteBatch.begin(...., transform)

    SpriteBatch.Draw( Texture, Black, Color);
    SpriteBatch.Draw( Texture, White, Color);

 SpriteBatch.end();
```

Basically you are working in a different space that is rotated ans translated as you need, realize that Black rectangle location is (0,0).

Code it's not tested but should work as expected. ;)